# Definition of 1 second

Tags: time, frequency, oscillators, si-units, metrology

> "One second is the time that elapses during 9,192,631,770 cycles of the radiation produced by the transition between two levels of the cesium 133 atom."

Can we alternatively define it as, **Frequency of Cs-133 atom?**

Comment: Time and frequency don’t even have the same dimensions. They are inverses of each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no such thing as "frequency of Cs-133 atom" to be defined. Atoms don't have any natural freqencies. But the light produced when atoms change their state does.

You can define the frequency of the light produced by the transition between two energy levels of Cs-133 to be 9,192,631,770 Hz, and that will lead to an equivalent definition of  a second. It just needs to be mentioned that the energy levels mentioned in this definition are not just any energy levels, they are very much specified - they are the levels that originate from the hyperfine splitting of the ground state of the atom. Transition between any other two states of this atom will produce light of a different frequency.

Comment: So you mean that my definition is very general and it can be wrong in case of other energy level transitions.

Comment: @YaseenKhan That it isn't precise enough, yes.

Answer (score -1):

This is **already** a definition based on cesium atom radiation frequency. By definition frequency is number of events per second. Cs-133 atom makes 9,192,631,770 radiation cycles per second, so it has $9\,192\,631\,770\,\textrm{Hz}$ radiation frequency. Or if we want to be inaccurate, then $\approx 9.193\,\textrm{GHz}$, this corresponds to electromagnetic waves in microwave spectrum region with $33\,\textrm{mm}$ wavelength.

The point why physicists were able to construct such definition of a second, is that they were able to measure wavelength and/or frequency of emitted electromagnetic wave (corresponding to Cs-133 atom transition between the two hyperfine levels of the ground state) **very accurately**.
I.e. high resolution of wavelength measurements enabled re-definition of second standard.

Comment: It's not a measure of events, but the the frequency associated with the energy difference of the hyperfine spliting of the ground state  via Planck's formula $E = h \nu$. There is nothing oscillating there. And it's not an emitted frequency that is measured, but the change in total spin due to the absorption of photons. Neither was it the resolution that enabled the redefinition of the second, that was already possible decades earlier, but reproducibility of a high accuracy frequency standard.

Comment: @AttilaKinali _any_ frequency is related to period like $T = 1/f$, thus you can define second as 9192631770 Cs-133 atom oscillations per second. Thus you are wrong

Comment: Sorry, there is nothing in the atom that oscillates. It's an energy difference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfine_structure

Comment: @AttilaKinali You totally don't know what you are talking about. When Cesium-133 atom transits between those two hyperfine ground levels - it absorbs specific frequency photons. Absorbed photon frequency is an electromagnetic wave oscillation. Check wiki page [Caesium standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesium_standard) : "_The caesium standard is a primary frequency standard in which the photon absorption by transitions between the two hyperfine ground states of caesium-133 atoms are used to control the output frequency._"

Comment: Yes, but the way you formulated your answer makes it sound like the atom oscillates.

Comment: @AttilaKinali Or simply you have interpreted me wrong.

Comment: @AttilaKinali isn't the electron in the hyperfine transition that's what oscillating 9,192,631,770 Hz?

Comment: @Aneikei No. The electron does not oscillate either. It has a potential energy depending on its state. Saying the electron oscillates is like saying a stone, that you carried up a mountain, oscillates. And don't confuse that with the solutions of the Schrödinger equation, which have to fulfill periodic conditions. That's something very different.

Comment: @AttilaKinali thanks for clarifying. So in the case of time dilation  is it the frequency of the photon that is being emitted from the electron transition that's undergoing a frequency shift?